# Redirecionamento usando parametros de url

Tags: javascript

Esse um é um código de redirecionamento, eu usava ele sem parametros de url, mas agora preciso que funcione de acordo com os parametros e não consegui, eu sou bem novo em javascript, será que alguém poderia me explicar o que estou fazendo de errado no meu código?
Se `ver` for igual a `1`, não fazer nada, caso contrario execute `window.location.replace("https://www.google.com");`

```
var url = new URL(window.location);
var ver = url.searchParams.get("ver");

document.onload = function() {

   if(ver == 1) {
      return false;
   }

   else {
      window.location.replace("https://www.google.com");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O evento `onload` não é aplicável ao `document`, mas ao objeto `window`.

Altere para:

```
window.onload = function() {...
```

Agora, não seria mais interessante verificar se `ver` é diferente de `1`, já que o `else` irá considerar qualquer valor diferente de `1`?

```
if(ver != 1) {
  window.location.replace("https://www.google.com");
}
```

Comment: pode me explicar a função da exclamação?

Comment: Sim: `!=` significa "diferente" e `==` significa "igual"

Comment: muito obrigado, isso vai me ajudar a simplificar muita coisa

Comment: Também tem `!==` que significa diferente no valor e no tipo, e `===` igual no valor e no tipo. Mais informações sobre operadores vc acha [neste link](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_operators)